# Best method to get over cross domain in javascript

Tags: javascript, dns

i have in my localhost:8111 a restlet app running. This app have a ServerResource that respond http requests from a javascript api that i'm doing.

This Javascript api is running in my apache in localhost, and i want to do http request to the localhost:8111, but i can't for the cross domain problem.

The restlet response in json, which solution is the best in this case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same as any other case.

- CORS if you want control and are willing to sacrifice some cross-browser support.
- JSON-P if you can live with GET only requests and no security over which sites can trigger the request
- A proxy on the same origin if you don't need the final server to get credentials directly from the client