# Getting response from server in javascript

Tags: javascript

How does I get the response from the server in JavaScript? This is my sample code:

```
function get_Image(values) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        var http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        var http_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } else {
        http_request.open("GET", "http://sample_address_for_server", true);
        http_request.send();
    }
    alert(http_request.status);
    if (http_request.readyState == 4) {
        if (http_request.status == 200) {
            xmlDoc = http_request.responseText;
            alert(xmlDoc);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I strongly suggest you use a framework like jQuery

Comment: What's the problem?  What have you tried?

Comment: Please format your JavaScript with clean indentation, it makes it much easier to read. What values do you get for your alerts? What error messages do you get? The fact your example URI is an absolute URI suggests you may be hitting the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Comment: trying to fetch the response from the cross domain, and return the response

Comment: Given the above comment this is a duplicate of [Best method to get over cross domain in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8136107/best-method-to-get-over-cross-domain-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Try using this block .. the problem with your code is that you missed the quote while creating the open connetion

```
function get_Image(values){ 

      var http_request = false;
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        http_request = new XMLHttpRequest()
      } else {
        if (window.ActiveXObject) {
          try {
            http_request = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
          } catch () {
            try {
              http_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
            } catch () {}
          }
        } else {
          return false
        }
      }
      http_request.onreadystatechange = function () {

       alert(http_request.status);    
          if ( http_request.readyState == 4 ) {    
         if ( http_request.status == 200 ) {    
        xmlDoc = http_request.responseText;    
            alert(xmlDoc);   
    }}
      };
     http_request.open( "GET", "http://sample_address_for_server", true);
        http_request.send(null);   
    }
```

Comment: exactly what error you are getting... is connection is building

Answer (score -1):

you have to attach a function to the object's onreadystatechange event. The way you are doing, you are trying to get the response imediately after you sent the request, you don't have any response yet.

```
function get_Image(values) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        var http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        var http_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } else {
        http_request.open("GET", "http://sample_address_for_server", true);
        http_request.send();
    }
    alert(http_request.status);
    http_request.onreadystatechange = function(){
       if (http_request.readyState == 4) {
           if (http_request.status == 200) {
               xmlDoc = http_request.responseText;
               alert(xmlDoc);
           }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Games of spot the difference are not fun.

Comment: dude, you are amazing for spotting that. I must be more amazing for having answered in the same minute as Kunal. thanks...

Comment: @Quentin i was hoping you would get my sarcasm, apparently not